How to Unwind / populate an Array in Mongoose Aggregate Pipeline
I'm working with Mongoose and trying to unwind/populate the comments.attachments field within an aggregation pipeline. Here's the relevant portion of my code:
const result = await Ticket.aggregate([
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', { $toObjectId: "667293eca3a67d7c5d9ff1e2" }] } } },
        { $unwind: '$comments' },
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$comments._id', { $toObjectId: "667382f627df37eb4e7a3220" }] } } },
 ])

This query successfully retrieves a ticket document and unwinds the comments array. However, the comments.attachments field remains an empty array even though there are attachments associated with the comment.
  [
     {
        _id: new ObjectId('667293eca3a67d7c5d9ff1e2'),
        referenceNo: 'TCK_06-19-2024_0001',
        subject: new ObjectId('6670dad080ea03a681f70295'),
        description: 'pero ang totoo, di bali na ako. ikaw lang iniisip ko.',
        priority: 'medium',
        status: 'open',
        initiator: new ObjectId('6670da9d80ea03a681f70292'),
        createdBy: new ObjectId('667106fff8abeeb0d87341ba'),
        assignedTo: null,
        attachments: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        comments: {
          userId: new ObjectId('6670db4180ea03a681f7029e'),
          content: '2nd comment w atta',
          attachments: [Array],
          _id: new ObjectId('667382f627df37eb4e7a3220'),
          createdAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z,
          updatedAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z
        },
       createdAt: 2024-06-19T08:16:44.129Z,
       updatedAt: 2024-06-20T02:14:51.282Z,
       __v: 0
      }
   ]

Here are my models for reference:
Ticket Model
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const ticketCommentSchema = require('./ticketCommentModel');
 const ticketAttachmentSchema = require('./ticketAttachmentModel');

 const ticketSchema = new Schema({
   // ... other schema properties
     comments: [ticketCommentSchema],
     attachments: {
     type: [ticketAttachmentSchema],
     required: true,
     validate: [attachmentsArray => attachmentsArray.length > 0, 'At least one attachment is   required']
   },
   }, {
     timestamps: true
   });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', ticketSchema);

Ticket Comment Model
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const ticketAttachmentSchema = 
  require('./ticketAttachmentModel');

 const ticketCommentSchema = new Schema({
   userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
   },
   content: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true
   },
   attachments: [ticketAttachmentSchema]
   }, {
   timestamps: true
   });

 module.exports = ticketCommentSchema;

Ticket Attachment Model
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const ticketAttachmentSchema = new Schema({
  // ... attachment schema properties
  }, {
    timestamps: true
       });

 module.exports = ticketAttachmentSchema;

My question is:
How can I modify the aggregation pipeline to unwind or populate the comments.attachments field and retrieve the attachment details within the query results?
I've searched online for solutions, but haven't found anything specific to this scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I try this aggregation pipeline
const result = await Ticket.aggregate([
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', { $toObjectId: "667293eca3a67d7c5d9ff1e2" }] } } },
        { $unwind: '$comments' },
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$comments._id', { $toObjectId: "667382f627df37eb4e7a3220" }] } } },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$comments.attachments",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
       ])`

and it returns this data
[
  {
   _id: new ObjectId('667293eca3a67d7c5d9ff1e2'),
   referenceNo: 'TCK_06-19-2024_0001',
   subject: new ObjectId('6670dad080ea03a681f70295'),
   description: 'pero ang totoo, di bali na ako. ikaw lang iniisip ko.',
   priority: 'medium',
   status: 'open',
   initiator: new ObjectId('6670da9d80ea03a681f70292'),
   createdBy: new ObjectId('667106fff8abeeb0d87341ba'),
   assignedTo: null,
   attachments: [ [Object], [Object] ],
   comments: {
     userId: new ObjectId('6670db4180ea03a681f7029e'),
     content: '2nd comment w atta',
     attachments: [Object],
     _id: new ObjectId('667382f627df37eb4e7a3220'),
     createdAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z,
     updatedAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z
   },
   createdAt: 2024-06-19T08:16:44.129Z,
   updatedAt: 2024-06-20T02:14:51.282Z,
   __v: 0
    },
  {
   _id: new ObjectId('667293eca3a67d7c5d9ff1e2'),
   referenceNo: 'TCK_06-19-2024_0001',
   subject: new ObjectId('6670dad080ea03a681f70295'),
   description: 'pero ang totoo, di bali na ako. ikaw lang iniisip ko.',
   priority: 'medium',
   status: 'open',
   initiator: new ObjectId('6670da9d80ea03a681f70292'),
   createdBy: new ObjectId('667106fff8abeeb0d87341ba'),
   assignedTo: null,
   attachments: [ [Object], [Object] ],
   comments: {
     userId: new ObjectId('6670db4180ea03a681f7029e'),
     content: '2nd comment w atta',
     attachments: [Object],
     _id: new ObjectId('667382f627df37eb4e7a3220'),
     createdAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z,
     updatedAt: 2024-06-20T01:16:38.190Z
    },
    createdAt: 2024-06-19T08:16:44.129Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-06-20T02:14:51.282Z,
    __v: 0
    }
   ]

it turns comment.attachments to object but still doesn't populate the data of attachments,
also the comment have 3 attachments.

Can you paste in a sample Ticket document from mongodb that has some comments.attachments data. Use mongosh or Compass to run the query so that the output prints nested objects. Otherwise just use console.dir(ticket, { depth: null }) to show all nested objects in the console.

this is my sample data for ticket documents https://mongoplayground.net/p/4lKLmnQRW90
and this is the result i am aiming
https://mongoplayground.net/p/mPAh_uJK9_f

the condition is base on 3 ObjectID:
ticketId = 6678d3b714c2fef2955395ca
ticket.commentId = 6678d63114c2fef2955395f0
ticket.comments.attachmentsId = 6678d63114c2fef2955395f1

note, the data that i provided in mongoplayground is different but the data structure in my actual is the same.

Apologies, I hadn't noticed you had uploaded some sample data. I've provided a solution that hopefully helps you.

This aggregation should get you the desired output.

$match: the ticket you want. Note the use of new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() constructor so that you don't have to use an $expr and convert $toObjectId.
$set: the comments array to the output from a $filter matching only comments that have an _id equal to ObjectId("6678d63114c2fef2955395f0").
$unwind: the comments array for the next stage. There should only be one object since you matched on _id.
$set: the comments.attachments array to the output from a $filter matching only attachments that have an _id equal to ObjectId("6678d63114c2fef2955395f1").

const result = await Ticket.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6678d3b714c2fef2955395ca"),
      "comments._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6678d63114c2fef2955395f0")
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      comments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$comments",
          as: "c",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$c._id",
              new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6678d63114c2fef2955395f0")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$comments"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "comments.attachments": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$comments.attachments",
          as: "ca",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$ca._id",
              new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6678d63114c2fef2955395f1")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);

See HERE for a working example.

Thank you so much, this works like a charm <3
